# IOS: insert a photo from camera in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, camera

In my app I use a custom camera and when I snap a photo I want to see it in an `UIImageView`, it's all ok it work, but there is a little problem: when it put the `UIImage` (from camera) in `UIImageView`, the image sems a little flattened, then what's the exactly resolution that I should to set for `UIImageView` to have an exactly copy of my original UIImage?

---

ok, I set aspect fill in IB and it's all ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images resolution depends on the device that you are using. For the iPhone 4, it's 2592x1936.

I think it's more likely that you might be looking for the aspect ratio for the image, which is always 4:3. Keep in mind however, that a) you don't know whether the image will be portrait or landscape and b) that, if you allow to take an image from a photo album, you don't have control over the resolution/ratio at all.

So the most prudent thing to do might be to just set the UIImages fill mode to 'Aspect Fill' or 'Aspect Fit'.